# Vertical-align: middle

Tags: css, alignment

I want to place the img element in the middle of div.partners-slider. This is a responsive slider i can't set fixed height. Any suggestions ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26y8t/)

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="ps-wrap"><div class="partners-slider">
<div class="pslide"><img src="http://server-pps.com/img/gwiazda_sponsor.png" /></div>  
<div class="pslide"><img src="http://www.sundance.org/images/support-us/HPActivitiesLogo50x50.png" /></div> 
<div class="pslide"><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvsT_kxUqdhOoo7zSTkbQ76PLgx4ZRucUZcbf2KsrY0bFbu30agw" /></div> 
    <div class="pslide"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/dr/nba/teamsites-nbateams/release/nets/sites/nets/files/content/images-gallery/2013/07/twitterimage-updated.jpg?1374006700" /></div> 
</div></div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.partners-slider').bxSlider({
slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 0,
        autoStart: 0,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 3,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        slideMargin: 5
  });
 });

(function(e){var t={},n={mode:"horizontal",slideSelector:"",infiniteLoop:!0,hideControlOnEnd:!1,speed:500,easing:null,slideMargin:0,startSlide:0,randomStart:!1,captions:!1,ticker:!1,tickerHover:!1,adaptiveHeight:!1,adaptiveHeightSpeed:500,video:!1,useCSS:!0,preloadImages:"visible",touchEnabled:!0,swipeThreshold:50,oneToOneTouch:!0,preventDefaultSwipeX:!0,preventDefaultSwipeY:!1,pager:!0,pagerType:"full",pagerShortSeparator:" / ",pagerSelector:null,buildPager:null,pagerCustom:null,controls:!0,nextText:"Next",prevText:"Prev",nextSelector:null,prevSelector:null,autoControls:!1,startText:"Start",stopText:"Stop",autoControlsCombine:!1,autoControlsSelector:null,auto:!1,pause:4e3,autoStart:!1,autoDirection:"prev",autoHover:!1,autoDelay:0,minSlides:1,maxSlides:1,moveSlides:0,slideWidth:0,onSliderLoad:function(){},onSlideBefore:function(){},onSlideAfter:function(){},onSlideNext:function(){},onSlidePrev:function(){}};e.fn.bxSlider=function(s){if(0!=this.length){if(this.length>1)return this.each(function(){e(this).bxSlider(s)}),this;var o={},r=this;t.el=this;var a=e(window).width(),l=e(window).height(),d=function(){o.settings=e.extend({},n,s),o.settings.slideWidth=parseInt(o.settings.slideWidth),o.children=r.children(o.settings.slideSelector),o.children.length<o.settings.minSlides&&(o.settings.minSlides=o.children.length),o.children.length<o.settings.maxSlides&&(o.settings.maxSlides=o.children.length),o.settings.randomStart&&(o.settings.startSlide=Math.floor(Math.random()*o.children.length)),o.active={index:o.settings.startSlide},o.carousel=o.settings.minSlides>1||o.settings.maxSlides>1,o.carousel&&(o.settings.preloadImages="all"),o.minThreshold=o.settings.minSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.minSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin,o.maxThreshold=o.settings.maxSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.maxSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin,o.working=!1,o.controls={},o.interval=null,o.animProp="vertical"==o.settings.mode?"top":"left",o.usingCSS=o.settings.useCSS&&"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&function(){var e=document.createElement("div"),t=["WebkitPerspective","MozPerspective","OPerspective","msPerspective"];for(var i in t)if(void 0!==e.style[t[i]])return o.cssPrefix=t[i].replace("Perspective","").toLowerCase(),o.animProp="-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transform",!0;return!1}(),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(o.settings.maxSlides=o.settings.minSlides),c()},c=function(){if(r.wrap('<div class="bx-wrapper"><div class="bx-viewport"></div></div>'),o.viewport=r.parent(),o.loader=e('<div class="bx-loading" />'),o.viewport.prepend(o.loader),r.css({width:"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?215*o.children.length+"%":"auto",position:"relative"}),o.usingCSS&&o.settings.easing?r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-timing-function",o.settings.easing):o.settings.easing||(o.settings.easing="swing"),v(),o.viewport.css({"max-width":"100%",overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}),o.viewport.parent().css({maxWidth:u()}),o.children.css({"float":"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?"left":"none",listStyle:"none",position:"relative"}),o.children.width(p()),"horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideMargin>0&&o.children.css("marginRight",o.settings.slideMargin),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideMargin>0&&o.children.css("marginBottom",o.settings.slideMargin),"fade"==o.settings.mode&&(o.children.css({position:"absolute",zIndex:0,display:"none"}),o.children.eq(o.settings.startSlide).css({zIndex:50,display:"block"})),o.controls.el=e('<div class="bx-controls" />'),o.settings.captions&&E(),o.settings.infiniteLoop&&"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&!o.settings.ticker){var t="vertical"==o.settings.mode?o.settings.minSlides:o.settings.maxSlides,i=o.children.slice(0,t).clone().addClass("bx-clone"),n=o.children.slice(-t).clone().addClass("bx-clone");r.append(i).prepend(n)}o.active.last=o.settings.startSlide==f()-1,o.settings.video&&r.fitVids();var s=o.children.eq(o.settings.startSlide);"all"==o.settings.preloadImages&&(s=r.children()),o.settings.ticker?o.settings.pager=!1:(o.settings.pager&&w(),o.settings.controls&&T(),o.settings.auto&&o.settings.autoControls&&C(),(o.settings.controls||o.settings.autoControls||o.settings.pager)&&o.viewport.after(o.controls.el)),s.imagesLoaded(g)},g=function(){o.loader.remove(),m(),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(o.settings.adaptiveHeight=!0),o.viewport.height(h());var redraw=setInterval(function(){r.redrawSlider()},25);setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(redraw)},250);$("#hide-menu-bg").mouseenter(function(){r.stopAuto(true)}).mouseleave(function(){if (o.settings.auto && o.settings.autoStart) L()}),sliderHover();$("#hide-menu-bg").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();var startTime=new Date().getTime();var interval=setInterval(function(){if(new Date().getTime()-startTime>1400){clearInterval(interval);sliderHover();return;}$('.slider-wrap').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');r.redrawSlider()},50);});function sliderHover(){$(".slider-wrap").mouseenter(function(){$(this).find(".slide-desc").css({left:'0'});$(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({'padding-left':'100px'});$(this).find(".slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({'left':'0'});}).mouseleave(function(){$(this).find(".slide-desc").css({left:'-200px'});$(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({'padding-left':'0'});$(this).find(".slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({'left':'500px'});})};$(window).resize(function(){r.stopAuto(true);setTimeout(function(){r.redrawSlider();if (o.settings.auto && o.settings.autoStart) {L()}},50);if(this.resizeTO)clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);this.resizeTO=setTimeout(function(){L()},500)}),o.settings.onSliderLoad(o.active.index),o.initialized=!0,o.settings.auto&&o.settings.autoStart&&L(),o.settings.ticker&&W(),o.settings.pager&&M(o.settings.startSlide),o.settings.controls&&D(),o.settings.touchEnabled&&!o.settings.ticker&&O()},h=function(){var t=0,n=e();if("vertical"==o.settings.mode||o.settings.adaptiveHeight)if(o.carousel){var s=1==o.settings.moveSlides?o.active.index:o.active.index*x();for(n=o.children.eq(s),i=1;o.settings.maxSlides-1>=i;i++)n=s+i>=o.children.length?n.add(o.children.eq(i-1)):n.add(o.children.eq(s+i))}else n=o.children.eq(o.active.index);else n=o.children;return"vertical"==o.settings.mode?(n.each(function(){t+=e(this).outerHeight()}),o.settings.slideMargin>0&&(t+=o.settings.slideMargin*(o.settings.minSlides-1))):t=Math.max.apply(Math,n.map(function(){return e(this).outerHeight(!1)}).get()),t},u=function(){var e="100%";return o.settings.slideWidth>0&&(e="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?o.settings.maxSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.maxSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin:o.settings.slideWidth),e},p=function(){var e=o.settings.slideWidth,t=o.viewport.width();return 0==o.settings.slideWidth||o.settings.slideWidth>t&&!o.carousel||"vertical"==o.settings.mode?e=t:o.settings.maxSlides>1&&"horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&(t>o.maxThreshold||o.minThreshold>t&&(e=(t-o.settings.slideMargin*(o.settings.minSlides-1))/o.settings.minSlides)),e},v=function(){var e=1;if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideWidth>0)if(o.viewport.width()<o.minThreshold)e=o.settings.minSlides;else if(o.viewport.width()>o.maxThreshold)e=o.settings.maxSlides;else{var t=o.children.first().width();e=Math.floor(o.viewport.width()/t)}else"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(e=o.settings.minSlides);return e},f=function(){var e=0;if(o.settings.moveSlides>0)if(o.settings.infiniteLoop)e=o.children.length/x();else for(var t=0,i=0;o.children.length>t;)++e,t=i+v(),i+=o.settings.moveSlides<=v()?o.settings.moveSlides:v();else e=Math.ceil(o.children.length/v());return e},x=function(){return o.settings.moveSlides>0&&o.settings.moveSlides<=v()?o.settings.moveSlides:v()},m=function(){if(o.children.length>o.settings.maxSlides&&o.active.last&&!o.settings.infiniteLoop){if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){var e=o.children.last(),t=e.position();S(-(t.left-(o.viewport.width()-e.width())),"reset",0)}else if("vertical"==o.settings.mode){var i=o.children.length-o.settings.minSlides,t=o.children.eq(i).position();S(-t.top,"reset",0)}}else{var t=o.children.eq(o.active.index*x()).position();o.active.index==f()-1&&(o.active.last=!0),void 0!=t&&("horizontal"==o.settings.mode?S(-t.left,"reset",0):"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&S(-t.top,"reset",0))}},S=function(e,t,i,n){if(o.usingCSS){var s="vertical"==o.settings.mode?"translate3d(0, "+e+"px, 0)":"translate3d("+e+"px, 0, 0)";r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-duration",i/1e3+"s"),"slide"==t?(r.css(o.animProp,s),r.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",function(){r.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),I()})):"reset"==t?r.css(o.animProp,s):"ticker"==t&&(r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-timing-function","linear"),r.css(o.animProp,s),r.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",function(){r.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),S(n.resetValue,"reset",0),H()}))}else{var a={};a[o.animProp]=e,"slide"==t?r.animate(a,i,o.settings.easing,function(){I()}):"reset"==t?r.css(o.animProp,e):"ticker"==t&&r.animate(a,speed,"linear",function(){S(n.resetValue,"reset",0),H()})}},b=function(){for(var t="",i=f(),n=0;i>n;n++){var s="";o.settings.buildPager&&e.isFunction(o.settings.buildPager)?(s=o.settings.buildPager(n),o.pagerEl.addClass("bx-custom-pager")):(s=n+1,o.pagerEl.addClass("bx-default-pager")),t+='<div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="'+n+'" class="bx-pager-link">'+s+"</a></div>"}o.pagerEl.html(t)},w=function(){o.settings.pagerCustom?o.pagerEl=e(o.settings.pagerCustom):(o.pagerEl=e('<div class="bx-pager" />'),o.settings.pagerSelector?e(o.settings.pagerSelector).html(o.pagerEl):o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-pager").append(o.pagerEl),b()),o.pagerEl.delegate("a","click",z)},T=function(){o.controls.next=e('<a class="bx-next" href="">'+o.settings.nextText+"</a>"),o.controls.prev=e('<a class="bx-prev" href="">'+o.settings.prevText+"</a>"),o.controls.next.bind("click",A),o.controls.prev.bind("click",P),o.settings.nextSelector&&e(o.settings.nextSelector).append(o.controls.next),o.settings.prevSelector&&e(o.settings.prevSelector).append(o.controls.prev),o.settings.nextSelector||o.settings.prevSelector||(o.controls.directionEl=e('<div class="bx-controls-direction" />'),o.controls.directionEl.append(o.controls.prev).append(o.controls.next),o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-controls-direction").append(o.controls.directionEl))},C=function(){o.controls.start=e('<div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-start" href="">'+o.settings.startText+"</a></div>"),o.controls.stop=e('<div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-stop" href="">'+o.settings.stopText+"</a></div>"),o.controls.autoEl=e('<div class="bx-controls-auto" />'),o.controls.autoEl.delegate(".bx-start","click",k),o.controls.autoEl.delegate(".bx-stop","click",y),o.settings.autoControlsCombine?o.controls.autoEl.append(o.controls.start):o.controls.autoEl.append(o.controls.start).append(o.controls.stop),o.settings.autoControlsSelector?e(o.settings.autoControlsSelector).html(o.controls.autoEl):o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-controls-auto").append(o.controls.autoEl),q(o.settings.autoStart?"stop":"start")},E=function(){o.children.each(function(){var t=e(this).find("img:first").attr("title");void 0!=t&&e(this).append('<div class="bx-caption"><span>'+t+"</span></div>")})},A=function(e){o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto(),r.goToNextSlide(),e.preventDefault()},P=function(e){o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto(),r.goToPrevSlide(),e.preventDefault()},k=function(e){r.startAuto(),e.preventDefault()},y=function(e){r.stopAuto(),e.preventDefault()},z=function(t){o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto();var i=e(t.currentTarget),n=parseInt(i.attr("data-slide-index"));n!=o.active.index&&r.goToSlide(n),t.preventDefault()},M=function(t){return"short"==o.settings.pagerType?(o.pagerEl.html(t+1+o.settings.pagerShortSeparator+o.children.length),void 0):(o.pagerEl.find("a").removeClass("active"),o.pagerEl.each(function(i,n){e(n).find("a").eq(t).addClass("active")}),void 0)},I=function(){if(o.settings.infiniteLoop){var e="";0==o.active.index?e=o.children.eq(0).position():o.active.index==f()-1&&o.carousel?e=o.children.eq((f()-1)*x()).position():o.active.index==o.children.length-1&&(e=o.children.eq(o.children.length-1).position()),"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?S(-e.left,"reset",0):"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&S(-e.top,"reset",0)}o.working=!1,o.settings.onSlideAfter(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index)},q=function(e){o.settings.autoControlsCombine?o.controls.autoEl.html(o.controls[e]):(o.controls.autoEl.find("a").removeClass("active"),o.controls.autoEl.find("a:not(.bx-"+e+")").addClass("active"))},D=function(){!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&o.settings.hideControlOnEnd?0==o.active.index?(o.controls.prev.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.removeClass("disabled")):o.active.index==f()-1?(o.controls.next.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.prev.removeClass("disabled")):(o.controls.prev.removeClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.removeClass("disabled")):1==f()&&(o.controls.prev.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.addClass("disabled"))},L=function(){o.settings.autoDelay>0?setTimeout(r.startAuto,o.settings.autoDelay):r.startAuto(),o.settings.autoHover&&r.hover(function(){o.interval&&(r.stopAuto(!0),o.autoPaused=!0)},function(){o.autoPaused&&(r.startAuto(!0),o.autoPaused=null)})},W=function(){var t=0;if("next"==o.settings.autoDirection)r.append(o.children.clone().addClass("bx-clone"));else{r.prepend(o.children.clone().addClass("bx-clone"));var i=o.children.first().position();t="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-i.left:-i.top}S(t,"reset",0),o.settings.pager=!1,o.settings.controls=!1,o.settings.autoControls=!1,o.settings.tickerHover&&!o.usingCSS&&o.viewport.hover(function(){r.stop()},function(){var t=0;o.children.each(function(){t+="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?e(this).outerWidth(!0):e(this).outerHeight(!0)});var i=o.settings.speed/t,n="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?"left":"top",s=i*(t-Math.abs(parseInt(r.css(n))));H(s)}),H()},H=function(e){speed=e?e:o.settings.speed;var t={left:0,top:0},i={left:0,top:0};"next"==o.settings.autoDirection?t=r.find(".bx-clone").first().position():i=o.children.first().position();var n="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-t.left:-t.top,s="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-i.left:-i.top,a={resetValue:s};S(n,"ticker",speed,a)},O=function(){o.touch={start:{x:0,y:0},end:{x:0,y:0}},o.viewport.bind("touchstart",N)},N=function(e){if(o.working)e.preventDefault();else{o.touch.originalPos=r.position();var t=e.originalEvent;o.touch.start.x=t.changedTouches[0].pageX,o.touch.start.y=t.changedTouches[0].pageY,o.viewport.bind("touchmove",B),o.viewport.bind("touchend",X)}},B=function(e){var t=e.originalEvent,i=Math.abs(t.changedTouches[0].pageX-o.touch.start.x),n=Math.abs(t.changedTouches[0].pageY-o.touch.start.y);if(3*i>n&&o.settings.preventDefaultSwipeX?e.preventDefault():3*n>i&&o.settings.preventDefaultSwipeY&&e.preventDefault(),"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&o.settings.oneToOneTouch){var s=0;if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){var r=t.changedTouches[0].pageX-o.touch.start.x;s=o.touch.originalPos.left+r}else{var r=t.changedTouches[0].pageY-o.touch.start.y;s=o.touch.originalPos.top+r}S(s,"reset",0)}},X=function(e){o.viewport.unbind("touchmove",B);var t=e.originalEvent,i=0;if(o.touch.end.x=t.changedTouches[0].pageX,o.touch.end.y=t.changedTouches[0].pageY,"fade"==o.settings.mode){var n=Math.abs(o.touch.start.x-o.touch.end.x);n>=o.settings.swipeThreshold&&(o.touch.start.x>o.touch.end.x?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide(),r.stopAuto())}else{var n=0;"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?(n=o.touch.end.x-o.touch.start.x,i=o.touch.originalPos.left):(n=o.touch.end.y-o.touch.start.y,i=o.touch.originalPos.top),!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&(0==o.active.index&&n>0||o.active.last&&0>n)?S(i,"reset",200):Math.abs(n)>=o.settings.swipeThreshold?(0>n?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide(),r.stopAuto()):S(i,"reset",200)}o.viewport.unbind("touchend",X)},Y=function(){var t=e(window).width(),i=e(window).height();(a!=t||l!=i)&&(a=t,l=i,r.redrawSlider())};return r.goToSlide=function(t,i){if(!o.working&&o.active.index!=t)if(o.working=!0,o.oldIndex=o.active.index,o.active.index=0>t?f()-1:t>=f()?0:t,o.settings.onSlideBefore(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index),"next"==i?o.settings.onSlideNext(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index):"prev"==i&&o.settings.onSlidePrev(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index),o.active.last=o.active.index>=f()-1,o.settings.pager&&M(o.active.index),o.settings.controls&&D(),"fade"==o.settings.mode)o.settings.adaptiveHeight&&o.viewport.height()!=h()&&o.viewport.animate({height:h()},o.settings.adaptiveHeightSpeed),o.children.filter(":visible").fadeOut(o.settings.speed).css({zIndex:0}),o.children.eq(o.active.index).css("zIndex",51).fadeIn(o.settings.speed,function(){e(this).css("zIndex",50),I()});else{o.settings.adaptiveHeight&&o.viewport.height()!=h()&&o.viewport.animate({height:h()},o.settings.adaptiveHeightSpeed);var n=0,s={left:0,top:0};if(!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&o.carousel&&o.active.last)if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){var a=o.children.eq(o.children.length-1);s=a.position(),n=o.viewport.width()-a.width()}else{var l=o.children.length-o.settings.minSlides;s=o.children.eq(l).position()}else if(o.carousel&&o.active.last&&"prev"==i){var d=1==o.settings.moveSlides?o.settings.maxSlides-x():(f()-1)*x()-(o.children.length-o.settings.maxSlides),a=r.children(".bx-clone").eq(d);s=a.position()}else if("next"==i&&0==o.active.index)s=r.find(".bx-clone").eq(o.settings.maxSlides).position(),o.active.last=!1;else if(t>=0){var c=t*x();s=o.children.eq(c).position()}var g="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-(s.left-n):-s.top;S(g,"slide",o.settings.speed)}},r.goToNextSlide=function(){if(o.settings.infiniteLoop||!o.active.last){var e=parseInt(o.active.index)+1;r.goToSlide(e,"next")}},r.goToPrevSlide=function(){if(o.settings.infiniteLoop||0!=o.active.index){var e=parseInt(o.active.index)-1;r.goToSlide(e,"prev")}},r.startAuto=function(e){o.interval||(o.interval=setInterval(function(){"next"==o.settings.autoDirection?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide()},o.settings.pause),o.settings.autoControls&&1!=e&&q("stop"))},r.stopAuto=function(e){o.interval&&(clearInterval(o.interval),o.interval=null,o.settings.autoControls&&1!=e&&q("start"))},r.getCurrentSlide=function(){return o.active.index},r.getSlideCount=function(){return o.children.length},$("#main-content").resize(function(){r.redrawSlider()}),r.redrawSlider=function(){o.children.add(r.find(".bx-clone")).width(p()),o.viewport.css("height",h()),o.settings.ticker||m(),o.active.last&&(o.active.index=f()-1),o.active.index>=f()&&(o.active.last=!0),o.settings.pager&&!o.settings.pagerCustom&&(b(),M(o.active.index))},r.destroySlider=function(){o.initialized&&(o.initialized=!1,e(".bx-clone",this).remove(),o.children.removeAttr("style"),this.removeAttr("style").unwrap().unwrap(),o.controls.el&&o.controls.el.remove(),o.controls.next&&o.controls.next.remove(),o.controls.prev&&o.controls.prev.remove(),o.pagerEl&&o.pagerEl.remove(),e(".bx-caption",this).remove(),o.controls.autoEl&&o.controls.autoEl.remove(),clearInterval(o.interval))},r.reloadSlider=function(e){void 0!=e&&(s=e),r.destroySlider(),d()},d(),this}}})(jQuery),function(e,t){var i="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";e.fn.imagesLoaded=function(n){function s(){var t=e(g),i=e(h);a&&(h.length?a.reject(d,t,i):a.resolve(d)),e.isFunction(n)&&n.call(r,d,t,i)}function o(t,n){t.src===i||-1!==e.inArray(t,c)||(c.push(t),n?h.push(t):g.push(t),e.data(t,"imagesLoaded",{isBroken:n,src:t.src}),l&&a.notifyWith(e(t),[n,d,e(g),e(h)]),d.length===c.length&&(setTimeout(s),d.unbind(".imagesLoaded")))}var r=this,a=e.isFunction(e.Deferred)?e.Deferred():0,l=e.isFunction(a.notify),d=r.find("img").add(r.filter("img")),c=[],g=[],h=[];return e.isPlainObject(n)&&e.each(n,function(e,t){"callback"===e?n=t:a&&a[e](t)}),d.length?d.bind("load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded",function(e){o(e.target,"error"===e.type)}).each(function(n,s){var r=s.src,a=e.data(s,"imagesLoaded");a&&a.src===r?o(s,a.isBroken):s.complete&&s.naturalWidth!==t?o(s,0===s.naturalWidth||0===s.naturalHeight):(s.readyState||s.complete)&&(s.src=i,s.src=r)}):s(),a?a.promise(r):r}}(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
    img.tab-ico {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;

}

.partners-slider {
height: 100%;
}

div.pslide {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

div.pslide img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}



.ps-wrap .bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.ps-wrap .bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.ps-wrap .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
}

.ps-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 18px;
  background: #d6d4c8;
  padding: 6px 0 6px;
}

.ps-wrap:before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAFCAYAAACEhIafAAAAJElEQVQImQEZAOb/AOXj1/8A5ePX/wDx7+L/ALy6sf8Az87C/97LEYJAFgv5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat-x;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ps-wrap:after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAFCAYAAACEhIafAAAAHklEQVQImWM4f+7Qf4Y9uzb+Z/j4/tF/hqePr0MIANUbEYIYiHfUAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat-x;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bx-controls-direction {
 position: absolute;   
top: 80px;
}
```

.................................................................................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that with an pseudo-element:

```
div.pslide {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

div.pslide:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}

div.pslide img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/26y8t/3/)

**How it works**
[image: Michał Czernow vertical align middle technie]

Its based on [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) CSSTricks post.

Comment: They look fine to me.  This is a very clever method for vertically centering content where both container and content dimensions are unknown. +1!

Comment: They look fine to me in any resolution.

Comment: oh, it works now ;D THANKS SO MUCH for your help, i spent too much time on this -.-'I really appreciate this !

Answer (score 2):

Why are you keeping it has a separate image.  Instead make it as the div's background like

```
style = "background:url('http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvsT_kxUqdhOoo7zSTkbQ76PLgx4ZRucUZcbf2KsrY0bFbu30agw')
no-repeat center center"
```

and position it both vertically and horizontally.

Here is the [**sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/26y8t/2/) of yours.

Comment: responsive won't work in this way, try to resize the window,

btw they are dynamically loaded from wordpress media library on my website