# Vertical align middle inside div columns

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Is it possible, with CSS, while using a row with two column, one with an image and another with text, to have their content vertically aligned in the middle?

I've been banging my head for days over this and tried everything I could possibly think of.

This is the basic structure that I'm using which is entirely based on percentages. This is for a responsive one-page layout based on a series of sections, each with min-height set to 100%.

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:table;
    height:inherit;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
}

.col-left, .col-right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*--this should be vertically centred--*/

.content {
}
```

HTML

```
<section>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-left">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-right">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="SOME IMAGE URL">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</section>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/dnqL9wtL/6/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical-align: middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168435/vertical-align-middle)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.row {
    ...
    display:table-row;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    ...
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dnqL9wtL/7/)**

Answer (score 3):

You were 95% of the way there as you laid out the structure using display:table, and display:table-cell, but you floated what should have been display:table-cell, and set table-cell on what should have been table row. Use this instead:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:table;
    height:inherit;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-row;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.col-left {
    background: MidnightBlue
}
.col-right {
    background: ForestGreen;
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-left">
            <div class="content">
                 <h1>I should be vertically aligned in the middle...<br><br>And so should the image on the right...
                </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not very good at this, plus, I never used this technique before to build columns. Usually I just use some variation of float left. Is one way more acceptable or preferred over the other? Your version vs David Rubin's below. Which is best? Or is it indifferent?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:table;
    height:inherit;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    float: left;
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-left {
    background: MidnightBlue
}
.col-right {
    background: ForestGreen;
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-left">
            <div class="content">
                 <h1>I should be vertically aligned in the middle...<br><br>And so should the image on the right...
                </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. David, both techniques work fine and I can't tell a difference in performance between them in any browser. I wonder if one is more recommendable over the other. @isherwood your suggestion vs David Rubin's; Which is preferable?

Comment: After further testing I found the solution provided by "isherwood" and "j08691" to be more comprehensible, much simpler and also more consistent. Getting rid of float also seams to me an advantage. It also doesn't require an extra container.  With the alternative you suggested I've noticed the row breaks when you shrink the window which would require extra fixing. Thanks for giving me the alternative though and the chance to compare. Not sure if this means I don't need to use float left again to build columns, but I hope it does.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this topic, this issue and the answers provided raised in me another question regarding which method to apply in this situation, and in fact, for building columns in general: **Floating or Display property**. For any newbie or self-taught wannabe developer like my self may be interesting to know what I've concluded after research and testing.

I find my self often using different methods for building columns that revolve around **Floating** the elements and in one way or another always require some hacking in the end to do exactly what I want, leaving me with a feeling of inconsistency and unreliability.

One would think that something so vital for layout structure would have at this point in time some obvious, elegant and simple solution. Apparently it has, and it's called **Display Table**. It might have limitations in some very specific situations but in general it's all you need. It's rock solid and you can pretty much do anything you want with it. Unfortunately, I think the word "table" is still a kind of taboo. This method however is simple, comprehensible, reliable and doesn't require any hacks to behave as expected. Vertical alignment which is always a struggle is also made easy this way.

A simple structure like this is all you need:

```
.container {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

For some reason (probably because of the nasty word "table"), you wont be able to find this method suggested anywhere with a simple search on basic css columns.

**I thought this articles on the subject were interesting:**

[**Give Floats the Flick in CSS Layouts**](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/)

[**Farewell Floats: The Future of CSS Layout**](http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/)